# High Oil consumption in my BMW x3 - 2014 - (F25) 2L Diesel engine

Tags: bmw, diesel, oil-consumption, x3

i have recently got my BMW x3 with 41,000 km on it 
after running for some time it asked for a oil 1L oil topup so i called BMW dealership and they asked me to get a castrol 5w30 and top it up and i did 
(the mechanic poured 1.5L oil)

after some more kilometers i had the same problem so i went to a nearby dealership and they topped up BMW twinturbo engine oil and asked me notedown the kilometers

so as expected it asked for a topup again and now i noted the kilometers and i found that it is 1800km interval

i know the oil consumption varies based on the driving pattern , but i dont usually floor the engine , i use the car only for long trips and it always runs in a highway around 120 - 140km/hr

my oilchange is in next 4.7k km so the service engineer advised me to have a engine oil consumption check  at the time of oil change , there is no oil leaks he said

does anyone know what the issue might be ?

Comment: Have you checked the handbook for any indication of a "normal" oil consumption?

Comment: no , let me check and update it here

Comment: No numbers were mentioned in the handbook